# WordPress woocommerce currency exchange issues

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an online shop using wordpress but the local currency of Pakistan is not supported which I managed to tackle by adding it in the code. The problem is that I use CCNOW as a payment gateway and it doesn't support my local currency so the only option I have is to change the currency to USD on checkout. That includes doing the currency exchange from Pakistan rupee to USD. Can anyone advise on what to do.

Comment: The Pakistani rupee is supported by WooCommerce. Are there no gateways that support Pakistani currency?

Comment: Yes, my main problem is on CCNOW. It does not support Pakistani currency so my only option is to exchange from Pakistani to USD on checkout. Is there a way out?